# Writing data to cells in Excel 2007 / PowerShell

Tags: .net, excel, api, powershell, ms-office

Why can I not write values to Excel using the Worksheet class, or Sheet interface? I would expect to be able to do something like this:

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel")
$Excel = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass
$Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Add()
$Worksheet = $Workbook.Worksheets.Add()
$Worksheet.Cells.Item(1,1).Value2 = "Test"
```

But instead, it seems that you have to write values using the ApplicationClass object:

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel")
$Excel = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass
$Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Add()
$Worksheet = $Workbook.Worksheets.Add()
$Excel.Cells.Item(1,1).Value2 = "Test"
```

This doesn't seem logical to me, because I'm writing the value to the specific worksheet I'm working with, not at the application level.

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot reproduce this. Your former example works perfectly for me. I verified by setting $Excel.Visible = $true and I can see "Test" in cell(1,1).

-Oisin

Comment: Ok, now I feel like an idiot ... I could have sworn I tried this a million times in the past and it never worked.

Move along, nothing to see here :(

Thanks for validating, guys ...